# sqlite Fetching sqlite error:W/CursorWindow(30274): Window is full: requested allocation 328 bytes, free space 39 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

- I am fetching data from the SQLite database inside my assets folder,
  I successfully can fetch that data but as well as I also get the
  window cursor error which slows down my app.

  class DatabaseHelper {
  static const dbName = "myDatabase.db";
  static const dbTable = "my_table";
  static const wordsTable = "bywords_table";
  static const columnId = "id";

  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = DatabaseHelper.internal();

  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get database async {
  if (_database != null) return _database;

  ```
   _database = await initDatabase();
   return _database;
  ```

  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  Future initDatabase() async {
  String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
  String path = join(databasesPath, 'myDatabase.db');
  bool exists = await databaseExists(path);

  ```
   if (!exists) {
     // Copy the database from assets to the device
     ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/sqlite_database/myDatabase.db");
     List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
     await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
   }

   // Open the database
   Database db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: true);

   return db;
  ```

  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchData() async {
  Database? db = await database;
  return await db!.query(dbTable);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchWords() async {
  Database? db = await database;
  return await db!.query(wordsTable);
  }

  Future close() async {
  Database? db = await database;
  return await db!.close();
  }
  }

Fetching data in the Flutter app using FutureBuilder->ListView.builder:

```
final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();

  List filteredList = [];

  Future loadData() async {
    final dbData = await dbHelper.fetchData();
    setState(() {
      //listData = dbData;
      filteredList = dbData.where((e) => e['data'] == widget.id).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }
```

Now need to solve the windowCursor error.